# Date format in our Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose, utc

**Can anyone tell me which is the right format to store date in my database.**

Suppose if the client and the server are in the same region, we can use unix epoch timestamp or date string. But if the server is in US and the client is from Asia, I knew people saying UTC to auto convert date from the particular region. But I cannot store UTC in MongoDB via Node js, maybe i made it in the wrong way.

.currently I store **"09-02-2021"** for date and **1612837056077** timestamp. I also get the time from the front end.Also, I am not sure with the above things. Can someone explain the right way of using date and time in a real world application. If possible show me a quick demo in node js and mongoose

*Thank you all :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTC is the way to go. I don't know what you mean by "But I cannot store UTC in MongoDB via Node js". Create your schema like so:

```
const client_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  ...
  date_created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  ...
  ...
});
```

And `date_created` will always be stored in UTC format. From UTC, you can convert it to any timezone. Here is just one example, using moment, of how to convert UTC to a Eastern Timezone:

```
const d = moment(utc_date).utcOffset(moment(utc_date).tz("America/New_York").format('Z'), true).toDate();
```

Note: `moment` is being phased out and is no longer recommended for new projects.

Comment: by default mongoDB saves in UTC , right? @codemonkey

Comment: @Jaga Absolutely. Which is super convenient because UTC can be converted to anything you want.

Comment: @Jaga If you see a date that ends with a `Z` in your documents, that's a UTC date. Example: `2021-02-03T20:38:24.070Z`

Comment: 2021-02-10T05:29:57.811+00:00 is this UTC. This is what MongoDB saves for me. @codemonkey

Comment: @Jaga This is not UTC format. It's just an ISO 8601 date and time. The time is the same as UTC because it has a zero offset from GTM `+00:00`, but what you're showing is not a UTC timestamp. Where do you see it? Log in to your mongodb terminal and run a find command on a collection that has a date in it. It should look like this: `ISODate("2020-02-19T12:15:57.372Z")`

Comment: Yes i see UTC format in mongo shell. But ISO time in MongoDB Compass.Is mongoDB compass converting it into my timezone???

While fetching data via postman i get this 2021-02-10T10:08:54.944Z ... This entire time i was looking at mongodb compass, which shows time in ISO.

Thank You so much:)

Comment: @Jaga Compass displays it in ISO 8601 Datetime format. So it's not a specific timezone, it's just displayed differently. ISO 8601 DateTime - `2021-02-10T13:02:29+00:00`, ISO 8601 UTC - `2021-02-10T13:02:29Z`. See, it's the same time, but formatted slightly differently.